# Summing values in one column until a certain value is encountered in another column

Tags: r

I am trying to sum a series of rows in one column until a value in another column that is greater or equal to a threshold number is encountered, outputting that sum into an object and repeating that process and putting the next sum into the same object.

I have used R mostly for statistics and my ability to write code is pretty limited and self-taught. Currently, I have a series of data sets and each data set represents an individual. Within each data set there are two columns of interest and roughly 17,000 rows. I am trying to sum consecutive rows from one column (x) until a value of 0.17 or greater is encountered in the other column (a). Once this value is encountered, I need that sum to be output into another object. Then, starting on the following row, I need to sum all the values in x until a value of 0.17 or greater is encountered in a. So, by the end, I will have an object that contains all these sums for the whole data set. I have tried some functions that use loop and if/else but am not getting sensible results. I'm not really even sure if this is the best approach, so any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
a <- c(0.05, .10, 0.1, 0.19, 0.12, 0.15, 0.20, 0.01, 0.08, 0.11, 0.18, 0.14, 0.17, 0.01, 0.02)

summing <- function(x) {
    s <- 0
    leng <- Inf
    n <- nrow(data2)
    for(x in 1:(n-1)){
        step2<- if(data2$a <= 0.17){
            s <- s + x[1]
        }   
    }
    return(results)
}
summing(data2$step)

summing <- function(x) {
    count <- 1
    begin <- 1
    results <- list()
    x <- rbind(x, c(1))
    n <- nrow(x)
    for(i in n){
        step <- sum(x[i,2], x[i + 1, 2])
        t <- x[i +1, 3]
        if(abs(x[i + 1, 3]) <= 0.17){
            begin <- i + step 
        }
        if(abs(x[i + 1, 3]) > 0.17){
            results[[count]] <- begin:1
            count <- count + 1
        }
    }
    return(results)
}
```

With this example data, I need an object that would sum the first four values together (10), then the 5th-7th (18), 8th-11th (26), 12th-13th (7), 14th-15th (3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tapply`

```
INDEX <- cumsum(a >= 0.17) - (a >= 0.17)
out <- tapply(X = x, INDEX = INDEX, FUN = sum)
out
# 0  1  2  3  4 
#10 18 26  7  3
```

Where `INDEX` is given by

```
INDEX
# [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

---

As pointed out by @d.b in the comments, another option to create that grouping vector is

```
INDEX = cumsum(c(FALSE, head(a, -1)) >= 0.17)
```

Comment: `INDEX = cumsum(c(FALSE, head(a, -1)) >= 0.17)` is another option

Comment: Awesome, this is it! Obviously I was overthinking it, which is so easy in R.